# TYPO3: How to set up textfield in custom content element to avoid missing file references in backend filelist?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

How to set up textfield in custom content element to avoid missing file references in backend filelist

I have a custom content element with a field of type "text". When I link in this field to a file in fileadmin there is no reference counted in the backend. 
How I have to configure the field in my TCA to regard the references from that field in the file list?

My TCA-Config for that field is:

```
'my_ext_fiedname' =>
                array(
                    'config' =>
                        array(
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'eval' => 'required',
                            'richtextConfiguration' => 'default',
                            'enableRichtext' => '1',
                        ),
                    'exclude' => '1',
                    'label' => 'title',
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using media references in text fields. It has been difficult over the past years to upgrade TYPO3 with such configuration and usages.
If you can't avoid, try using extension [rte_ckeditor_image](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/rte_ckeditor_image/) from Christian Opitz which is regularly maintained.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but that's no option for that customer. I do not want to add images in the text field itself, but I have to link to files from within the text field. In the standard textmedia content element this works in my TYPO3 instance. Therefore I thought I have missed something to configure in my custom CE.

Comment: Dmitry Dulepov found this issue today https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88462